# Cannot write files in cache directory

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm not able to write files in cache directory

```java
val file = File(context.cacheDir, usbFile.name)
val bufferedOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(usbFile.name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).buffered()
val bufferedInoutStream = UsbFileInputStream(usbFile).buffered()

var read = 0
while ({ read = bufferedInoutStream.read(); read != -1 }()) {
    bufferedOutputStream.write(read)
}
```

it works fine using context.filesDir but not context.cacheDir..
I'm using [libaums](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums) Library to read USB files.

Comment: you literally don't use that `file` object, so I'm not really what your question is?

Comment: If you want to write to `file`, replace `val bufferedOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(usbFile.name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).buffered()` with `val bufferedOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file).buffered()`.

Answer (score 1):

`openFileOutput()` writes to the filesystem location where `getFilesDir()` points. `openFileOutput()` is unrelated to `getCacheDir()`.

So, if you want to write to `getCacheDir()`, since you already have `file` pointing there, replace:

```kotlin
val bufferedOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(usbFile.name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).buffered()
```

with:

```kotlin
val bufferedOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file).buffered()
```